# Measuring PSU Voltage and Current using serial port VIA visual basic

Tags: visual-studio, serial-port, real-time-data

I have been tasked with designing a Visual Basic UI that interacts with a power supply unit, displaying the current and voltage on a RealTime XY Plot.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Sorry if my question is vague.

Comment: VB6? VBA? VB.Net?

Comment: VB.net, sorry I forgot to mention I am also using HyperTerminal...not sure if that is relevant.....thank you so much!

Comment: For .net, a class `SerialPort` exiists, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: Thank you for the help, unfortunately as I am only a beginner with VB.net the link you provided is only confusing me more.

Comment: The example is already as simple as possible (you just need to translate the syntax to VB.Net). You need to create an instance of the SerialPort-class, set the parameter (Port, Baudrate...) and create a Thread that reads the data.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to figure it out from the link you provided.